# Selecting in rails with an array and a element-related-condition

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have an array of products ids, which I would like to use for filtering a list of buying sessions. So far so good:

```
Session.where('product_id': [23, 32, 17])
```

I also have an array of dates, which specify for each product (differently) from which date should I even consider their sessions: `['12/2/17', '1/1/17', '20/3/17']`

So in other words: product id 23, should only be considered for sessions created after 12/2/17, product id 32, should only be considered for sessions created after 1/1/17, and so on...

What is the right rails command to also consider the product dates when selecting sessions about the wanted product ids?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, chaining your `where` clauses to your needs.

```
Session.where('product_id = ? AND date > ?', 23, Time.new(2017, 2, 12))
  .or(Session.where('product_id = ? AND date > ?', 32, Time.new(2017, 1, 17)))
```

Comment: Thats what I have for now as the 'naive' solution (I think). will it be maybe faster to add a column of the date dynamically (in a kind of a 'join' operations) and then use the column data in another where clause?

Comment: @dneumark You can probably generate this programmatically. For example (apologies for the poor formatting within a comment): create a 2D array: `where_clause = [ [23, '12/2/17'], [32, '1/1/17'], [17, '20/3/17'] ]`. Then iterate through it `where_clause.each do |(product, date)|`, and apply the clause: `Session.or(Session.where('product_id=? AND date>?', product, date))`